Sorting listobject function stops working randomly (error 1004)
I'm having trouble with a tiny function i wrote years ago, used to simply sort a specific column from A>Z of a list object.
It's randomly failed "Method range of object - 'Global' failed"
But if i press F5 again when stuck, it continue normally (sometimes).
I don't understand how can i debug this, could you please help ?
For better understanding: gracode_Dico is a global dictionary used to get the correct value of the code with the lo name as imput.
The code fail at the line .SortFields.Add2 key:=Range(sRange), SortOn:= _
'Boucle sur All Listobjects si leur nom est t_, puis trie selon le code de la table.
Private Function GRA_Tri_By_Code(theworkbook As Workbook)

Dim sRange As String, ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject

For Each ws In theworkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 2) = "t_" Then
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If Left(lo.Name, 2) = "t_" Then
            Select Case lo.Name
            Case "t_cable_patch201", "t_ltech_patch201", "t_zpbo_patch201", "t_cab_cond", "t_cond_chem", "t_love"
                'Debug.Print "Impossible de trier " & lo.Name
            Case Else
                sRange = lo.Name & "[[#All],[" & gracode_Dico(lo.Name) & "_code]]"
                'sRange = lo.Name & "[[#All],[" & "ba" & "_code]]"
                With lo.Sort
                    .SortFields.Clear
                    .SortFields.Add2 key:=Range(sRange), SortOn:= _
                    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .Header = xlYes: .MatchCase = False: .Orientation = xlTopToBottom: .SortMethod = xlPinYin: .Apply
                End With
            End Select
        End If
    Next lo
    End If
Next

End Function

I've tried to use ws.activate (not fond of it), no changes.
I've tried to precise the parent of the range like ws.Range(sRange) or lo.Range(sRange) without success.

Possibly just qualify the range with the worksheet i.e. ... Key:=ws.Range(sRange) ... I would rather use a range variable: Dim crg As Range: Set crg = lo.ListColumns(gracode_Dico(lo.Name) & "_code").Range ... Key:=crg ... BTW, this is not a function, it is a sub since there is no result i.e. Private Sub... and the calling code is e.g. GRA_Tri_By_Code ThisWorkbook without parentheses.

Thank's a lot for your response, it was indeed the right solution !
I've changed function to sub.
It's strange because this code was made 2 years ago, and it's not working anymore.
I've got the same problem on similar subs.
Time to fix this and test.
Many thanks.

I don't understand how can I debug this. Add some error checking and/or diagnostic debug.print statments. For example
Option Explicit

Private Sub GRA_Tri_By_Code(theworkbook As Workbook)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject
    Dim n As Long, sColumn As String
    
    For Each ws In theworkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 2) = "t_" Then
        For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
            If Left(lo.Name, 2) = "t_" Then
                Select Case lo.Name
                Case "t_cable_patch201", "t_ltech_patch201", "t_zpbo_patch201", "t_cab_cond", "t_cond_chem", "t_love"
                    'Debug.Print "Impossible de trier " & lo.Name
                Case Else
                
                    ' check dictionary
                    If gracode_Dico.exists(lo.Name) Then
                        sColumn = gracode_Dico(lo.Name)
                    Else
                        MsgBox "No entry for " & lo.Name & " in gracode_Dico", vbCritical
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                
                    ' check column exists
                    Dim rngSort As Range
                    For n = 1 To lo.ListColumns.Count
                         'Debug.Print ws.Name, lo.Name, lo.ListColumns(n).Name, sColumn
                         If lo.ListColumns(n).Name = sColumn Then
                            Set rngSort = lo.ListColumns(n).Range
                            Exit For
                         End If
                    Next
                    
                    ' does not exist
                    If rngSort Is Nothing Then
                       MsgBox "Could not locate column '" & sColumn & _
                       "' in " & ws.Name & " " & lo.Name, vbCritical
                       Exit Sub
                    End If
                    
                    With lo.Sort
                        .SortFields.Clear
                        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rngSort, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .Header = xlYes:
                        .MatchCase = False:
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                        .Apply
                    End With
                    
                End Select
            End If
        Next lo
        End If
    Next
End Sub

